# create a view to display events that are modified from yesterday 10am to today 9 am

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

create a view to display events that are modified from yesterday 10am to today 9 aM. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I tried creating a view with modified date today and am not sure what to specify for time in the filter column

Answer (score 1):

try to create view by sharepoint designer. this should allow you to use the today's date (which in turn can be used as today's date -1 ) and display the view.

Comment: Thanks for the respone. Yea created view and in filter field how can i mention from yesterday 10am to today 9 am. Not sure how to specify both time and day in filter column

Comment: you will have to calculate the time ie yesterday 10 AM to today 9 AM in terms of seconds and then check if modified date of the item lies between those number i.e. xxxx (yesterday date + time in sec) < yyy (item modified date in sec) > zzz (today date + time in sec)